# rename multiple complex file names using linux terminal

Tags: regex, linux, rename

I have over 1000 files with crazy names like `Name of file (V1.2) (N) [!].zip` and i need to remove the `(V1.2) (N) [!]` part of the name so that the new name for each file would be just `Name of file.zip` without any of the extra gibberish on the brackets or parenthesis.

here is one example: `File name (F) [!].zip`

for this I tried using `rename` on terminal like this:

```
$ rename 's/(F)//' *zip
```

this fails to delete the `(F)` and instead deletes the first letter `F` that it encounters, renaming the file `ile name (F) [!].zip` need help please, I cant figure it out.

also, on some of these i don't know what will be inside the parenthesis or how long it will be

Comment: Assuming your `rename` supports EREs, `(F)` matches a literal `F` and puts it into capture group one, you need to escape brackets like `\(F\)` to match them literally.

Comment: `(F)` is interpreted as a capture group - you need to escape the parentheses with backslashes.  `rename 's/\(F\)//' *zip` should give you the desired result.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 thank you that worked for most but what if i don't know what will be inside of the parenthesis, is there a way to remove that???

Comment: @37712 Yes, look up regular expressions.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 thank you kind sir, may god bless you with a bunch of kids.